# why is the same page Layout different for different profiles?

Tags: salesforce

I have 2 profiles, that for the same record type are assigned the same page layout. When I login as a user of 1 profile- i see a section and fields in the PL, but i don't in the other profile.

What's going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely he issue is going to be field level security at the profile level. You will need to review the profiles and look for inconsistencies between the two.

Comment: That would explain fields, but not the section, or would it?

Comment: If there are no fields to display in that section because of security the section won't appear